# Where are you supposed to put new application defaults for Rails 5+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm upgrading from 4.2.3 to 5.2.2.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#new-framework-defaults

Where do I put these new defaults? I tried to put them in `config/initializers/config.rb` but it said

> C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/app/config/initializers/config.rb:38:in 'block in ': undefined method 'active_record' for Config:Module (NoMethodError)

I saw a new file file `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb` and saw that `config/environments/development.rb` starts with `Rails.application.configure do` and has lines like `config.active_record.migration_error` so I added the following to `new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb`

```
Rails.application.configure do |config|
  config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
  config.action_controller.per_form_csrf_tokens = true
...
```

But it said

> C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/app/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb:43:in 'block in ': undefined method 'active_record' for # (NoMethodError)

So where do I put them?

Comment: Can't you put your configurations in `config/environment/development.rb` (or `production` or `test`, as appropriate)?

Comment: In all 3 places? You mean repeat myself?

Comment: That did work...

Comment: You can place them in `config/environment/*.rb` if they vary per environment or in `config/application.rb` if they are constant.

Comment: I think that perhaps your configs are invalid. Can you post the contents of your configs here, so we can see?